# Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth-zipkin:jar is missing

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, zipkin

Verified that following snippets are in the pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and below configured as a property :
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies. There was a typo. I had below in pom.xml. Once changed this to "spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin", jar was successfully loaded by maven.

spring-cloud-starter-sleuth-zipkin